# Lambda expression in JAVA for Nested Conditions

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have the following `Map`:

```
HashMap<String, String> map1= new HashMap<String, String>();
map1.put("1", "One");
map1.put("2", "Two");
map1.put("3", "Three");
```

I have a list `numbers` which contains `["1","2","3"]`

I have to perform the following operations:

```
List<String> spelling= new ArrayList<>();
for (String num: numbers) {
    if (map1.containsKey(num)){
        spelling.add(map1.get(num))
    }
}
```

How can I write the above code using lambda Expressions?

Comment: Downvoted for lack of attempt and prior research. I am sure there are zillion of similar questions around.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a `Stream`:

```
List<String> spelling = numbers.stream()
                               .map(map1::get)
                               .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println (spelling);
```

Note that instead of checking if a key is in the map with `containsKey`, I just used `get`, and then filtered out the `null`s.

Output:

```
[One, Two, Three]
```

Comment: What is the use of `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` ? I mean `map` will return only those objects which matched the passed key..

Comment: @MehrajMalik If the key is not in the map, `map1.get(k)` will return `null`.

Comment: Ahh! I didn't notice that. +1 for `.filter(Objects::nonNull)`

Comment: Note that if `map1` would possibly contain `null` values, this solution might give an unexpected result (depending on whether you want to retain those `null` values in the output)

Comment: @Ward Yes, if `map1` contains `null` values and you wish to keep them in the output, you'll have to use `.filter(k->map1.containsKey(k))`.

Answer (score 5):

A variant of [Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48048632/1649029)s solution:

1. Uses method references
2. Uses `containsKey` instead of checking `null` values => if `map1` would contain `null` values, checking `null` values would give a wrong result.

Code fragment:

```
List<String> spelling = numbers.stream()
        .filter(map1::containsKey)
        .map(map1::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println (spelling);
```

Comment: Don't like this, it calls `Map.get` twice. There is no reason to do this; Eran's answer is better.

Comment: Depends on the desired outcome: if you want to retain `null` values, using `containsKey` is simply the only way, and Erans answer will yield wrong results. 
Even if you don't want to retain `null` values, one _could_ argue that the version with `containsKey` expresses more clearly the intention of the code.

Comment: That's fair - in the case where that is the desired outcome then `containsKey` is required. But I'm not sure that the intent argument is valid - I would argume that the intent is clear either way but that using `containsKey` has double the overhead of the `null` check.

Answer (score 2):

another option would be to use the `forEach` construct:

```
numbers.forEach(n -> { 
       if(map1.containsKey(n))
           spelling.add(map1.get(n));
});
```

Comment: Not sure this really adds anything over a normal `foreach` loop, besides complexity. I dislike these uses of `forEach`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider agreed that it doesn't add anything over a normal `foreach` loop . However, it's just that OP wanted to use _"lambda"_ and hence the suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, understood - just wanted to say that this isn't really idomatic Java 8; more just using lambdas for the sake of it. Not convinced it's really useful, but it isn't wrong or harmful, so just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
 List<String> spelling = map1.keySet().stream()
                    .filter(numbers::contains)
                    .map(map1::get)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Very inefficient compared to the other answers. You have provided an `O(n*m)` solution (`n` is `map1.size()`, `m` is `numbers.size()`) rather than an `O(m)` solution.

Comment: Also, the order of result list may not correspond to the `numbers` list, as `HashMap` has no guaranteed iteration order.